# Kunen's exercise II. 27

Tags: set-theory

Trying to solve Kunen's exercise 27 in chapter 2 of his set theory (1980), I come across the proof that the following set of conditions is CCC : $ \mathbb{P} = \{ s \subset \omega_1 : card(s) = w \land \mu (\cap_{\alpha \in s} A_{\alpha}) > \epsilon  \} $ where the $A_{\alpha}$ are Lebesgue measurable sets, for $\alpha < \omega_1$, with $\mu(A_{\alpha}) > \epsilon$. I take a subfamily $ \mathcal{F} = \{p_{\alpha} : \alpha < \omega_1\}$ of sets of size $\omega_1$ and I want to show that there exist $\alpha \neq \beta$ such that $p_{\alpha} \cup p_{\beta} \in \mathbb{P}$. I disjoint them by taking the following sequence, $A_0, A_1\backslash A_0, ..., A_{\alpha} \backslash \cup_{\beta < \alpha} A_{\beta}$, for $\alpha < \omega_1$ (where I use the notation $A_{\alpha} := \cap_{\beta \in p_{\alpha}} A_{\beta}$). Then I use the fact that only countable many disjoint sets can be of non-zero measure among them. But I can't quite see how to conclude.
Am I on the right track ? Thanks in advance for any advice.